# Can i get the local public ip address who visit my website?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Can someone help me how can i get the local public address who visit my website?
Right now, i can get the the ip address of internet provider. I want the ipv4 address. Thank you.

Joshua

Comment: Not sure with what you meant. you want the Local ip of the network where the user is, instead of the ISP with which he connects to your app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Javascript's new WebRTC protocol to query for the local ip address of the network, which you can then transfer to your rails application using a cookie or ajax request.

The proof of concept of the webRTC request.

http://net.ipcalf.com/

You can get the code from there.

Comment: Thanx for this reply. Is there's a API that i can used for this site?

Comment: that is just a demo of the code. You will have to use the same code as mentioned there. Since WebRTC is now supported by all the browsers.

Comment: Can you help to use this site without redirecting to that url, i can get the IP address?

Comment: What you mean i use the same code?

Comment: right click, view page source. You will the js code they used.

Answer (score 1):

Might be you want this

```
$.getJSON("http://jsonip.com/",
  function(data){
      console.log(data);
       alert( data.ip);
  });
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/m236uyop/)**

Comment: I believe he is asking for the local IP of the network, your solution would give only the ISP ip address

Comment: Thanx for the reply, I try this code. but it returns the http://whatismyipaddress.com/. I like to return the ip address of machines. For example when i used my machine my ip is 192.168.1.x.

Answer (score 1):

There are two methods available in the controller to determine the remote ip address where a request came from:

1. `request.ip`, that might return a local proxy ip (if you are using a proxy or load balancer).
2. `request.remote_ip`, that looks also into the `HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR` header and might (depending on your setup) return a more accurate result.

Comment: hanx for the reply, I try this code. but it returns the whatismyipaddress.com. I like to return the ip address of machines. For example when i used my machine my ip is 192.168.1.x

Comment: You are aware that `192.168.1.x` is a local ip that is not visible to servers outside your network? The result of whatismyipaddress is what servers will see. What is your usecase?